# declaration type primitives with Object causes errors

Tags: typescript

Code:

```
export type TestType =
  | string
  | number
  | { value?: string, label?: string }
  | { num1: number, num2: number }
  | null;

const data: TestType;
data?.value // error;
```

error:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'TestType'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'
```

it's works fine if:

```
const data: TestType = { num1: 10, num2: 20 };
console.log(data.num1);
```

But the problem is: this type used in an array of objects where it can be one of the described types at runtime

Comment: That's working as I'd expect it to. In the first case, The TS compiler knows that `data` will be one of the union types you provided, but it has no idea which one. When you try to access `value` on `data`, the compiler rightly says "wait no, this could be a bunch of incompatible types"

Comment: @Nick I guess I got it: the way to use it is like this `(data as Partial<{value: string, label: string}>).value`, and that works fine, thanks

Comment: @Nick can you post it like an answer and I'll mark it as a right answer as well :)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow how you solved it... why don't you post the answer! That's pretty common here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix is to use `as`:

```
type ObjectType = {
  value: string,
  label: string
};

export type TestType =
  | string
  | number
  | ObjectType
  | null;

const data: TestType;

(data as ObjectType)?.value; // works
```